# What is the most efficient way to make money?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

What are some of the most efficient ways to make money?

Based on:

- time
- initial investment
- required progress (in the game)
- special equipment/gear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to make money quickly:

#### Stocks

If you can hold off until the end of the game to do Lester's side missions for Franklin, you can make hundreds of millions of dollars per character by investing in the stocks with each character before each mission.

This is the number one fastest method of earning money in the game.

#### Hidden Packages

Finding the respawnable underwater hidden packages would be the next fastest. Each hidden package has anywhere from $12.5K to $25K.

What you can do is quickly switch between characters then back to your original character. You will

1. Still be underwater next to the hidden package,
2. The package will respawn, and
3. Your oxygen supply will be refilled.

You can easily earn $25K every 10 seconds this way.

Edit: The second method is no longer repeatable after Rockstar issued a patch for GTA5. However, before applying the patch this would still be valid.